# Is a visa extended or issued?

Tags: word-choice

**Original Question:**

Should I request an embassy to extend me a visa or issue me a visa?

---

Just the way an [invitation is extended](https://www.gymglish.com/en/english-translation/extend-an-invitation), I thought I could ask embassies for extending me a visa. With that thought I have written supporting letters to embassies, asking to extend me a visa and I have been granted visas as well, without any embassy getting confused about whether I'm asking for a new visa or requesting extension of an existing one.

However, ***this doesn't mean that the my usage was correct***.

They probably just did not read the letter or maybe ignored my incorrect English. It was a non-issue until this time when I got response back from someone (not working at the embassy) telling me to write another letter that is about issuing me a new visa, instead of extending me a visa.

I looked up online to see whether I committed a mistake and could find no place which clearly says that visas cannot be extended (so as to mean - "be newly issued" rather than extending a current one) and exclusively have to be issued.

There is [enough material, though,  to understand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_visa) that *a request to extend a visa can be easily confused with requesting extension for a visa*.

But then ***this too doesn't mean that 'extending a visa' cannot be used for conveying the request to issue a new visa.***

My comprehensive questions:

- Is there any authoritative answer that tells the correct method to request a visa stamp on your passport?
- Is there any authoritative answer that tells that asking the embassy to *extend* a visa is wrong?
- Yes, I can write the letter, requesting the embassy to *grant* me a visa. I'd like to know if this is indeed the most appropriate way?

  - In that case, is requesting to 'extend me a visa' an exclusively wrong phrase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Issuing** a visa implies requesting the embassy to provide a visa.

**Extending** a visa implies prolonging an already issued visa.

If you need the embassy to provide a visa, then you would request them to **issue** one.

If you already have been issued a visa with a specified number of days and would like to add to that, then you would request the embassy to **extend** the given visa.

References:
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/issue
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/extend

Generally, formal documents are “issued” by a party. In this case, a visa is an authorization that can only be issued by the embassy; it cannot be extended as an invitation.

Reference: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/issue_2

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. The question was not requesting the embassy to "extend a visa" but "extend **us** a visa".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Generally, formal documents are “issued” by a party. In this case, a visa is a document that can only be issued by the embassy; it cannot be extended as an invitation.

Reference:http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/issue_2

Comment: Please alter your answer, explaining why a visa cannot be extended.

Comment: Please see [the 8th meaning here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/extend?q=extend). Can you explain why a first issuing of the visa cannot be called 'extending a visa'?

Comment: The link mentions the different meanings of ‘extend’; each will apply to a particular context. Given your context, using ‘extend’ would be incorrect. The first issuing of a visa can't be called ‘extending a visa’ because there is nothing to extend or prolong. Also, in #8, note the meaning of 'extend' and the examples provided: it involves ‘offering’ a warm welcome, etc. My previous comment mentions that formal documents/authorizations are “issued” and not extended as an invitation. Moreover, it was you who took the initial action of applying for a visa. The embassy did not ‘offer’ it to you.

Comment: To continue @starfish's excellent comment: You can "_extend an invitation_" to someone – that is, spontaneously _offer_ them an invitation. The corresponding use involving a visa would require an _embassy_ to spontaneously offer to "_extend a visa_" to you... which clearly does not happen (they don't pick people at random and offer them visas). Technically, you could probably ask someone to "_extend an invitation to me_" (i.e. ask to be invited), but this is clumsy (both socially and linguistically). However, I don't believe you could ask an embassy to "_extend a visa to me_" [cont...]

Comment: [...] because – as mentioned – embassies don't _offer_ visas... you have to apply for one. So you ask/apply for them to "_issue_ [a new] visa" or to "_extend_ [an existing] visa".

Comment: @TripeHound: I agree with your point that asking someone to extend an invitation to me is clumsy. But "extending an invitation" doesn't have to be spontaneous. It can be a properly thought out act. Could you please link me to further explanation that extending of invitation is related to spontaneity of it?

Comment: @displayName Ok, "spontaneity" is possibly the wrong (or at least a superfluous) word – "_at their instigation_" or, colloquially, "_off their own bat_" might be better. The idea I was trying to convey is that _extending an invitation_ is an act the _other party_ decides to do (whether after careful deliberation or spontaneously). However, an embassy will not decide (neither after careful thought nor spontaneously) to offer (=extend) a visa to someone (if they have not already applied for one). Therefore, asking them to do so ("_please extend me a visa_") would be wrong (not to say confusing).